# When do Go's pointers dereference themselves

Tags: pointers, go

I just started diving into Go recently and I have one major point of confusion: I am struggling to understand when exactly it is necessary to dereference a pointer explicitly.

For example I know that the `.` operator will handle dereferencing a pointer

```
ptr := new(SomeStruct)
ptr.Field = "foo" //Automatically dereferences
```

In what other scenarios does go do this? It seems to for example, with arrays.

```
ptr := new([5][5]int)
ptr[0][0] = 1
```

I have been unable to find this in the spec, the section for pointers is very short and doesn't even touch dereferencing. Any clarification of the rules for dereferencing go's pointers would be great!

Comment: Related question with very informative answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849751/rule-for-go-pointers-references-dereferencing

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The [selector expression](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) (e.g. `x.f`) does that:

> Selectors **automatically dereference pointers** to structs. If `x` is a pointer to a struct,
> `x.y` is shorthand for `(*x).y`; if the field `y` is also a pointer to a struct, `x.y.z` is
> shorthand for `(*(*x).y).z`, and so on. If `x` contains an anonymous field of type `*A`, where
> `A` is also a struct type, `x.f` is a shortcut for `(*x.A).f`.

The definition of the [index expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Index_expressions) specifies that an array pointer may be indexed:

> For a of pointer to array type:
>
> - `a[x]` is shorthand for `(*a)[x]`

Comment: So there is no mention of automatic dereferencing beyond the selector expression in the spec?

Comment: I haven't found it. Either I'm blind or it may be an omission in the specs. Someone should probably fill an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/list).

Comment: I just edited the post to explain how array pointers can be indexed.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. Read it twice before and I was really blind :-(

Comment: But the following fails:

`s := &[]Struct{Struct{Name:"Test"}}
 fmt.Println(s[0].Name)`

Comment: I feel like if Go made the decision to allow both pointer and non-pointer object references, they should not have this mixing of sometimes auto-deferencing and sometimes not. It would be much more clear to use `.` on direct references and `->` on pointers, so it is at least clear when something is a pointer or not. And having to do (*x) all the time is the whole point of having the `->` operator.

Comment: There is no conflation between pointers and arrays in go as there is in c/c++ (ie there is no pointer arithmetic). As such the only things you can access with index expressions are slices/maps/arrays.