# Rule for Go Pointers, References, Dereferencing:

Tags: pointers, reference, go, pass-by-reference

I am new to GoLang, coming from the Delphi, C++ world - admittedly very excited about this language, which I think is destined to become "the next big thing".

I am trying to get a handle around how the Go parser and compiler handle pointers and references - can't seem to find any place where some clear rules are laid out.

In the below code sample  for example, the return type `*list.List` and the local variable `l` are pointer types and require the pointer symbol `*` in their declarations, but they don't have to be dereferenced in use: `l.PushBack(i)`. But in this same code the input parameter `value *int64` is declared as a pointer and has to be dereferenced to be used properly: `var i int64 = *value / 2`

I assume that this is because `list.List` is a reference type, so the dereferencing is implicit when used, while `int64` is a value type and must be handled just as any pointer to a value type, as in C++ for example: It must be dereferenced.

What is confusing to me is that even though `*list.List` has to be declared as a pointer type using `*`, when using the list instance, dereferencing is not required. This had me quite confused initially. Is that "just the way it is", or am I missing something?

**Sample:**

```
func GetFactors(value *int64) *list.List {

    l := list.New()

    l.PushBack(*value)

    var i int64 = *value / 2

    for ; i > 1; i-- {

        if *value%i == 0 {

            l.PushBack(i)

        }
    }

    return l

}
```

Comment: No, there's no Java silliness and type racism in Go. Rather, there is automatic pointer dereferencing when you call "member" functions. (Those functions are actually defined out of line.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All of the methods for a `List` have `*List` receivers: (http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/)

```
func (l *List) Back() *Element
func (l *List) Front() *Element
func (l *List) Init() *List
...
func (l *List) Remove(e *Element) interface{}
```

In your example `l` is of type `*List`, so there's no need to dereference them.

Suppose, instead, that you had something like this:

```
type A struct{}
func (a  A) X() {
    fmt.Println("X")
}
func (a *A) Y() {
    fmt.Println("Y")
}
```

You are allowed to write:

```
a := A{}
a.X()
a.Y() // == (&a).Y()
```

Or you can do the following:

```
a := &A{}
a.X() // same like == (*a).X()
a.Y()
```

But it only works for method receivers. Go will not automatically convert function arguments. Given these functions:

```
func A(x *int) {
    fmt.Println(*x)
}
func B(y int) {
    fmt.Println(y)
}
```

This is invalid:

```
A(5)
```

You have to do this:

```
var x int 
A(&x)
```

This is also invalid:

```
var y *int
B(y)
```

You have to do this:

```
B(*y)
```

Unlike C# or Java, when it comes to structs, Go does not make a distinction between reference and value types. A `*List` is a pointer, a `List` is not. Modifying a field on a `List` only modifies the local copy. Modifying a field on a `*List` modifies all "copies". (cause they aren't copies... they all point to the same thing in memory)

There are types which seem to hide the underlying pointer (like a slice contains a pointer to an array), but Go is always pass by value.

Comment: OK - this finally made some sense to me. I'm finding a big learning curve with go -it **looks like** C/C++ but it doesn't act like it...

Comment: There is still something I'm confused about - see [Move semantics in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849911/move-semantics-in-golang) : when should I be returning a reference: *list.List and when is list.List just as good.

I understand that if I want to modify a value 'in place' then I need a reference, but for example in my sample code, where just the return value is  list.List, do I gain anything but returning a reference like in my sample, instead of what would be in C++ a copy, if not for the new 'move semantics' in C++11?

Comment: It's similar to value vs reference types in C# (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx). In this case you definitely want to use `*List`. Although `List` might work, it only makes a copy of the first element. The rest of the linked list will be shared, which could result in some strange behavior if you modify it.

Comment: The best approach when learning go after C/C++ is probably to assume nothing about the pointer system. The language spec on some of the dereferencing is [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values), and defines when implicit conversions take place. e.g.: "As with selectors, a reference to a non-interface method with a value receiver using a pointer will automatically dereference that pointer: pt.Mv is equivalent to (*pt).Mv. "

Comment: why does go implicitly convert values to pointers for method receivers expecting pointers? Why not have the compiler complain about a type mismatch instead? This "selective implicit conversion some of the time" is confusing to me as a beginner with go.

Comment: It is described in language specs: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_values
```
As with selectors, a reference to a non-interface method with a value receiver using a pointer will automatically dereference that pointer: pt.Mv is equivalent to (*pt).Mv.

As with method calls, a reference to a non-interface method with a pointer receiver using an addressable value will automatically take the address of that value: t.Mp is equivalent to (&t).Mp.
```