# Go sorts slice correctly, but doesn't sort array

Tags: go

I'm puzzled as why this code doesn't work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type T [2]int

func (t T) Len() int           { return len(t) }
func (t T) Swap(i, j int)      { t[i], t[j] = t[j], t[i] }
func (t T) Less(i, j int) bool { return t[i] < t[j] }

func main() {
    var x = [2]int{1, 0}
    fmt.Println(x)
    sort.Sort(T(x))
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

It outputs (incorrectly):

```
[1 0]
[1 0]
```

Changing the type of T to slices does the correct thing.

Comment: IMO, Swap does not do anything to the receiver, i.e. `t := T(x) t.Swap(0, 1)` will cause nothing.

Comment: [Everything in Go is passed (and assigned) by value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20856597/720999), and arrays are not an exception.  Slices have the so-called "reference semantics" meaning that their values contain a reference to the underlying data storage and hence passing a slice to a function *copies the slice value* but *the copy shares* the underlying data storage* with the original slice value.

Comment: kostix, your link mentions that "everything in Go is passed by value, but there are three buit-in "reference types" which are passed by value as well but internally they hold references to separately maintained data structure: maps, slices, channels".

But I can't find anything mentioning that in the official [Go spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec). Have I missed something? Thanks.

Comment: @epsylon, no, I think you didn't. My take on this is that the spec is kind of a legal document: it might be too succinct but in exchange it's minimal -- it only defines what formally matters. The concept of types whose values have reference semantics is called here to help people understand why they behave in the way they behave; they might very well not exist *formally* in the language, and so they do.

Comment: @epsylon, you might also look  at this from another angle: the spec does not explain "whys" and nether does it describe how a concept it defines behaves differently to a similar concept found in other specs. Say, if assignment of maps cloned those maps, the spec would supposedly define that explicitly, but since they don't, the spec is silent on this.

Comment: @epsylon, when referring to a user in a comment, please present the `@` character to the user's nickname, otherwise they won't receive any notification about your comment.

Comment: @epsylon, by the way, this [FAQ entry](http://golang.org/doc/faq#references) sheds some light on "whys" of these peculiar built-in types.

Comment: @kostix: thanks. I understand the rationale (I've a long time C and C++ practicioner). My single biggest problem with Go so far is that I've never been able to find clear semantics from the official documentation. Things like, what exactly is a string, what's the exact type of a floating point literal... A formal spec is really a better format for this kind of things, rather than the readable but informal current spec or a few blog posts on the official Go blog.

Comment: @epsylon, well, I share your perception, but as to strings and f.p. constants, the spec is clear on these points: [strings are sequences of bytes](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types), they imply no *inherent* interpretation, but other parts of the spec define when such interpretation happens, and how (`range` is one example); [f.p. literals are constants](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Floating-point_literals), and those [are well-defined](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants), including restrictions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slices are inherently reference types, meaning the slice header contains a pointer to the backing array, so they can be mutated without a pointer receiver. Arrays not being a reference type, are copied in full when calling your methods.

In order to do this with an array you need to change everything to use pointers, so your code might look something like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type T [2]int

func (t *T) Len() int           { return len(t) }
func (t *T) Swap(i, j int)      { t[i], t[j] = t[j], t[i] }
func (t *T) Less(i, j int) bool { return t[i] < t[j] }

func main() {
    var x = T([2]int{1, 0})
    fmt.Println(x)
    sort.Sort(&x)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```