# What is the difference between the following two ways to initialize the user variable?

Tags: go

I am a starter in Golang. This question may be very easy but it really confused me.

if there is a User struct:

```
type user struct{
    name string
    email string
}
```

What is the difference between the following two ways to initialize the user variable?

```
mike := user{"mike", "mike@email.com"}
lisa := &user{"lisa", "lisa@email.com"}
```

Comment: Work through the Tour of Go and focus on https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1 ff.

Answer (score 1):

Variable `mike` is a variable of type `user` while `lisa` is a pointer, the type is `*user`.

Expression `&user{…}` means *take a pointer to a new user object*.

Comment: if there is a fucntion: func (u user) notify{......}, `mike.notify()`and`lisa.notify()`and`(*lisa).notify()`are the same?

Comment: @luoyhang003 Yup, "automatic dereferencing": https://stackoverflow.com/a/13533822/3861083

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in initializing the instance user struct.
There's a big difference in how it is accessed in the target variable.

1. Case 1, it copies the user struct value into the mike variable
2. Case 2, it refers the user struct value using the lisa variable

See this snippet:

```
type user struct {
    name  string
    email string
}

someuser := user{"mike", "a@a.com"}
mike := someuser
lisa := &someuser

someuser.name = "hello"
fmt.Println(mike.name)    //name is not changed since user struct is copied
fmt.Println(lisa.name)    //name is changed since user struct is referred
```