# Go: I get a struct field value without deferencing the pointer variable of the struct type, why?

Tags: go, pointers, reference, go-gorm

```golang
// config/config.go

package config

import (
        "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

type Config struct {
        Database DatabaseConfig `mapstructure:"database"`
        Server   ServerConfig   `mapstructure:"server"`
        Redis    RedisConfig    `mapstructure:"redis"`
        Jwt      JwtConfig      `mapstructure:"jwt"`
        Smtp     SmtpConfig     `mapstructure:"smtp"`
}

func New() (config *Config) {
        viper.AddConfigPath(".")
        viper.SetConfigName("config")

        if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        if err := viper.Unmarshal(&config); err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        return
}
```

```golang
// db/connection.go
package db

import (
        "fmt"

        "my.project/config"
        "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
        "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func New(config config.DatabaseConfig) *gorm.DB {
        dsn := fmt.Sprintf(
                "%s:%s@tcp(%s:%d)/%s?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local",
                config.Username, config.Password, config.Host, config.Port, config.Database,
        )

        db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Failed to connect to database")
                panic(err)
        }

        RunMigrations(db)

        return db
}
```

```golang
// main.go
package main

import (
        "fmt"

        "my.project/config"
)

func main() {
        config := config.New()
        fmt.Println(config.Database)
        db := db.New(config.Database)

        if db == nil {
                panic("Failed to connect to database")
        }
}
```

In the above snippets, `config` is a pointer to a Config type variable (apparently from the return type of `config.New()`), but `config.Database` seems to be a value (not a reference).
I assumed `config.Database` would be a reference either but it's not (I tried to print out them, `config` was definitely a reference and `config.Database` was a value).
Can anyone help me to understand why? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go for language fundamentals. There are no references in Go. Why do you thin config.Database would be a pointer when it is declared as `Database DatabaseConfig`.?

Comment: Thanks, good call, I won't use "reference type" later on.  
And I'm still curious, `config` is a pointer variable, which holds just a memory address as its value, but how come `config.Database` returns value? Shouldn't it be `*config.Database`? I know I'm wrong, just struggling to get it right.

Comment: When you write `config.Database` the Go compiler knows that `config` is a pointer and translates it to (*config).Database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out that this was originated from one of the language design decisions. In fact, if you use `(*config).Database`, it is absolutely valid. However, the makers of Go deemed this notation cumbersome, so the language permits us to write `config.Database`,
without an explicit dereference. These pointers to structs even have their own name `struct pointers` and they are automatically dereferenced. Here's another superb explanation for "auto-deferencing": [When do Go's pointers dereference themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533681/when-do-gos-pointers-dereference-themselves)